# fullcalendar v5 - open a modal when click on icon in daygrid top

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, fullcalendar, icons

I have a problem on fullcalendar V5.

I put an icon on the top of the daygrid.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3npc.png)

I want to show a modal (#ModalEditAbsence) when i click on it.

The modal is showed so it's ok, but a another modal (the one which is open on select option of fullcalendar : #ModalAddAbsence) is open too.

So i have 2 modals open in the same time...

Here is the code of the icon, on DayCellContent option of fullcalendar:

```html
'<a onClick="teletravail_click(this.id)" href="#" class=" fa fa-home" id="'+ nom_tel[k] + couleur_tel[k] +'" aria-hidden="true" title="' + nom_tel[k] + '" data="' + couleur_tel[k] + '"style="color:' + couleur_tel[k] +'"></a>';
```

```js
    function teletravail_click(id) {
        var teletravail = document.getElementById(id);
        $('#ModalEditAbsence #event_id').val('103');
        $('#ModalEditAbsence #task').val('Télétravail');
        $('#ModalEditAbsence #user').val(teletravail.getAttribute("data"));
        $('#ModalEditAbsence #description').val('');
        $('#ModalEditAbsence').modal('show');
    }
```

i tried to add $('#ModalAddAbsence').modal('hide'); in teletravail_click function but it doesn't work.

if someone have a solution...thank you !

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Do you want to close one modal when another opens or do you want to have both open at the same time?

Comment: i just want to have the #ModalEditAbsence open when i click on the icon. But the #ModalAddAbsence also open because the icon is in the day grid. I would like to disable that, as when i click on the day number.

Comment: the code for click on the day number is : <a class="fc-daygrid-day-number" data-navlink="{"date":"2020-09-09","type":"day"}" tabindex="0">9</a>. The data-navlink seems to block the openning of the #ModalAddAbsence modal. But i can't use it to open the #ModalEditAbsence

Comment: Would you not be better off representing absence as an event? It's not clear why you've invented these icons for it.

Comment: Because i already have a lot of events (activities and absence) and i want that those events (tele-working) to be clearly visible with an icon on the top of the day grid

Comment: but if you have a better solution to do what i want, i'm listennig. The way i choose it's probably, and surely not the better solution :)